# protobuf message holding reference to another message of same type

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, self-reference

I have a `Player` structure which holds a list of pointers to its closest neighbors. The structure might look as follows in C++:

```
struct Player {
  string handle;
  vector<Player*> neighbors;
};
```

I want to use protobuf to serialize instances of this class. How would I write a message definition to represent the above structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of "reference" in protobuf.

Therefore the sanest way to do it would be to:

```
message Player {
  required string handle = 1;
  repeated string neighborHandles = 2;
};
```

Usually you would then convert them to C++ references when you are done deserializing.

Comment: Strangely protobuf.net provides some support for references.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do the trick:

```
message Player
{
  required string handle = 1;

  repeated Player neighbors = 2;
}
```

I compiled the definition with protobuf-c and it seems to be working.

Comment: The problem with this definition is that neighbors holds instances and not references. I am looking for a way to represent a reference (like a pointer) to another object.

Comment: You could introduce a playerIdentifier into player and use that to identify the neighbors.