# Encode/decode strings inside byte type in nanopb with C

Tags: c, string, void-pointers, nanopb

I have a `.proto` file that looks like this:

```proto
message ObjValue
{
// ...
    optional bytes byteval    = 6 [max_size = 256]; // arbitrary structure or message
// ...
```

I use this proto encoding to send structs that change. This struct basically contains ints and strings (a null-terminated char array).

The sender sends the struct doing something like this:

```c
   // Here I create the struct and fill it with integers and strings
   struct flow_msg *flow_msg = malloc(sizeof(struct flow_msg));
    flow_msg->dst_addr        = 1;
    flow_msg->src_addr        = 2;
    flow_msg->src_ap_name     = strdup(src_ap_name);

    // Here I save the length of the struct and a void pointer that points to the struct
    struct ser_obj_value *obj_value = malloc(sizeof(struct ser_obj_value));
    obj_value->size = sizeof(struct flow_msg) + strlen(src_ap_name) + 1; // +1 because of '\0'
    obj_value->data = flow_msg;
```

Then, the receiver gets the message, decodes it using nanopb and then:

```c
int
handle_msg(void *f_msg)
{
    struct flow_msg *flow_msg = (struct flow_msg *)f_msg;
}
```

At that point, if I try to read the value of an integer there's no problem (`flow_msg->dst_addr`, for example), but if I want to read the string value, I get a null pointer because the `flow_msg->src_ap_name` is empty.

I'm  lost in terms of how I should properly encode/decode the string value... Really don't know what I'm missing here... Any clues?

Comment: Your code is hard to follow, but I think the main thing is that your structure (and thus the protobuf message) does not actually contain the string, only a pointer to it. Once you deserialize it on the other side, the pointer is just to a random location in memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually only wrote the relevant code chunks in order to make it more understandable. The `nanopb` encoding part is not there because is well tested and I'm pretty sure that it works well. But then, if the problem is in the encoder side, am I doing something wrong in the code I wrote?

Comment: Is the type of the `src_ap_name` field `char *` or similar? In that case, you are just sending a memory address over. And because the other application does not share the same memory, that memory address will be useless. Kind of related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084673/representing-pointer-variables-in-protobuf-c)

Comment: Yes, is a `char *` type. Thanks for pointing out, what you say makes sense. But by doing `strdup()` I'm already malloc-ing the string in memory, so I should be saving the string in memory already.

Comment: Sure, it is in the memory on the machine that is sending. But it is completely elsewhere in memory than the struct, and the struct is the only thing you are sending over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I realize now how silly my question was. Actually, I'm not deleting it because @jpa took some time to try to answer my doubts.

Mainly the problem was that I was trying to send pointers (i.e., memory addresses) and then the receiver of course did not know what to do with this random memory address. Also, the problem was that I was "unlucky" that probably because I was using the same machine and same compiler in the receiver side some pointers were actually properly dereferenced, and that confused me a lot.